# How can I speed up my query. subquery is too slow

Tags: mysql

The query I have is for a table of inventory.  What the subquery join does is gets the total number of work orders there are for each inventory asset.  If I run the base query with the main joins for equipment type, vendor, location and room, it runs just fine.  Less than a second to return a result.  using it with the subquery join, it takes 15 to 20 seconds to return a result.

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT `inventory`.inventory_id AS 'inventory_id', 
       `inventory`.media_tag AS 'media_tag', 
       `inventory`.asset_tag AS 'asset_tag', 
       `inventory`.idea_tag AS 'idea_tag', 
       `equipTypes`.equipment_type AS 'equipment_type',  
       `inventory`.equip_make AS 'equip_make', 
       `inventory`.equip_model AS 'equip_model', 
       `inventory`.equip_serial AS 'equip_serial', 
       `inventory`.sales_order AS 'sales_order', 
       `vendors`.vendor_name AS 'vendor_name', 
       `inventory`.purchase_order AS 'purchase_order', 
       `status`.status AS 'status', 
       `locations`.location_name AS 'location_name', 
       `rooms`.room_number AS 'room_number', 
       `inventory`.notes AS 'notes', 
       `inventory`.send_to AS 'send_to', 
       `inventory`.one_to_one AS 'one_to_one', 
       `enteredBy`.user_name AS 'user_name', 
       from_unixtime(`inventory`.enter_date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'enter_date', 
       from_unixtime(`inventory`.modified_date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'modified_date', 
       COALESCE(at.assets,0) AS assets 
FROM mod_inventory_data AS `inventory` 
LEFT JOIN mod_inventory_equip_types AS `equipTypes` 
       ON `equipTypes`.equip_type_id = `inventory`.equip_type_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_vendors_main AS `vendors`  
       ON `vendors`.vendor_id = `inventory`.vendor_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_inventory_status AS `status`  
       ON `status`.status_id = `inventory`.status_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_locations_data AS `locations`  
       ON `locations`.location_id = `inventory`.location_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_locations_rooms AS `rooms`  
       ON `rooms`.room_id = `inventory`.room_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_users_data AS `enteredBy`  
       ON `enteredBy`.user_id = `inventory`.entered_by
LEFT JOIN  
       ( SELECT asset_tag, count(*) AS assets 
         FROM mod_workorder_data 
         WHERE asset_tag IS NOT NULL 
         GROUP BY asset_tag ) AS at  
       ON at.asset_tag = inventory.asset_tag 
ORDER BY inventory_id ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

The MySQL EXPLAIN data for this is here

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                                 | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | inventory          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                | 12612 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | equipTypes         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | spsd_woidbs.inventory.equip_type_id |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | vendors            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | spsd_woidbs.inventory.vendor_id     |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | status             | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | spsd_woidbs.inventory.status_id     |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | locations          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | spsd_woidbs.inventory.location_id   |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | rooms              | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | spsd_woidbs.inventory.room_id       |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | enteredBy          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | spsd_woidbs.inventory.entered_by    |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>         | ALL    | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                                |  4480 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | mod_workorder_data | range  | asset_tag     | asset_tag | 13      | NULL                                | 15897 | Using where; Using index        |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Using MySql query profiling I get this:

```
+--------------------------------+------------+
| Status                         | Time       |
+--------------------------------+------------+
| starting                       |  0.000020  | 
| checking query cache for query |  0.000263  |
| Opening tables                 |  0.000034  |
| System lock                    |  0.000013  |
| Table lock                     |  0.000079  |
| optimizing                     |  0.000011  |
| statistics                     |  0.000138  |
| preparing                      |  0.000019  |
| executing                      |  0.000010  |
| Sorting result                 |  0.000004  |
| Sending data                   |  0.015103  |
| init                           |  0.000094  |
| optimizing                     |  0.000009  |
| statistics                     |  0.000049  |
| preparing                      |  0.000022  |
| Creating tmp table             |  0.000104  |
| executing                      |  0.000009  |
| Copying to tmp table           | 15.410168  |
| Sorting result                 |  0.009488  |
| Sending data                   |  0.000215  |
| end                            |  0.000006  |
| removing tmp table             |  0.001997  |
| end                            |  0.000018  |
| query end                      |  0.000005  |
| freeing items                  |  0.000112  |
| storing result in query cache  |  0.000011  |
| removing tmp table             |  0.000022  |
| closing tables                 |  0.000036  |
| logging slow query             |  0.000005  |
| logging slow query             |  0.000005  |
| cleaning up                    |  0.000013  |
+--------------------------------+------------+
```

which shows me that the bottle neck is copying to temp table, but I am unsure of how to speed this up.  Are there settings on the server end that I can configure to make this faster?  Are there changes to the existing query that I can do that will yield the same results that would be faster?

It seems to me that the LEFT JOIN subquery would give the same resulting data matrix every time, so if it has to run that query for every row in the inventory list, I can see why it would be slow.  Or does MySQL cache the subquery when it runs?  I thought I read somwhere that MySQL does not cache subqueries, is this true?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How much data is in these tables you're querying? And have you made sure that all of the columns you're using for your join predicates are indexed?

Comment: The inventory data table has 12,612 records and the workorder data table in the subquery has 19,159 records.  I do have indexes for all of the ID fields and the asset_tag field used in the JOINs.  I meant to indicate that in the original post but forgot.  Should I have them all in one named index?  I currently have separate indexes.  BTW, thanks for reformatting the post.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't sound like a massive amount of data and I don't think that combining indexes will yield that much of a boost. To troubleshoot the perf. issue I would actually start by dismantling the query. Remove a join at a time and benchmark the performance. Doing so may reveal a problem somewhere. Maybe start by removing the subquery and see how that performs. If it alone is the culprit then an option may be to denormalize the data and create a table that holds those counts.

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that if I run the base query with all joins except the subquery join, it runs fine.  I just ran it and the query took 0.0215 seconds.  I already knew that the bottleneck was with the subquery.  If I run the subquery by itself it takes 0.0016 seconds for that,  If I multiply that number by the number of records (12,612) in the inventory table, I get 20.1792 seconds which is only 5 seconds difference between that and the full query/subquery.

Comment: Sorry, that was hours ago, i spaced. I think creating a denormalized table with prepopulated counts of your asset_tag field and performing a regular join on it will be your best shot at performance improvement.

Comment: i think your problem is the 'ORDER BY inventory_id ASC' cause query slow,please put your "SHOW CREATE TABLE mod_inventory_data "

Comment: Can I ask why you might think it is the ORDER BY?  As mentioned, the only time the query is slow is with the JOINed subquery added to the mix.  If I remove the COALESCE and the JOINED subquery, the query runs in a fraction of a second.  And that is WITH the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I am leaning towards Paul's solution of a denormalized data table that will hold the counts.  Basically a table with the results of the subquery for it's data set.  I would then use a standard LEFT JOIN to retrieve the counts instead of the subquery.  Thanks for the suggestion Paul.

Comment: I came across this question after hitting the same problem in the Security Suite module for SugarCRM. The quick solution for me has been to generate a temporary table, give it an index (important) and then join to the temporary table, as suggested here. To me this looks like an issue specifically with MySQL, and wondered if this is a known bug, or a reported issue, or just a known limitation? It appears to me that MySQL does not index its sub-query internally generated in the left join. In my case, queries lasting for over two minutes were reduced to about a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did which seems to be working good.  I created a table called mod_workorder_counts.  The table has two fields, Asset tag which is unique, and wo_count which is and INT(3) field.  I am populating that table with this query:

```
INSERT INTO mod_workorder_counts ( asset_tag, wo_count ) 
select s.asset_tag, ct 
FROM
  ( SELECT t.asset_tag, count(*) as ct
    FROM mod_workorder_data t
    WHERE t.asset_tag IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY t.asset_tag
  ) as s
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mod_workorder_counts.wo_count = ct
```

which executed in 0.1580 seconds which may be considered slightly slow, but not bad.

Now when I run this modification of my original query:

```
SELECT `inventory`.inventory_id AS 'inventory_id', 
       `inventory`.media_tag AS 'media_tag', 
       `inventory`.asset_tag AS 'asset_tag', 
       `inventory`.idea_tag AS 'idea_tag', 
       `equipTypes`.equipment_type AS 'equipment_type',  
       `inventory`.equip_make AS 'equip_make', 
       `inventory`.equip_model AS 'equip_model', 
       `inventory`.equip_serial AS 'equip_serial', 
       `inventory`.sales_order AS 'sales_order', 
       `vendors`.vendor_name AS 'vendor_name', 
       `inventory`.purchase_order AS 'purchase_order', 
       `status`.status AS 'status', 
       `locations`.location_name AS 'location_name', 
       `rooms`.room_number AS 'room_number', 
       `inventory`.notes AS 'notes', 
       `inventory`.send_to AS 'send_to', 
       `inventory`.one_to_one AS 'one_to_one', 
       `enteredBy`.user_name AS 'user_name', 
       from_unixtime(`inventory`.enter_date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'enter_date', 
       from_unixtime(`inventory`.modified_date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'modified_date', 
       COALESCE(at.wo_count, 0) AS workorders 
FROM mod_inventory_data AS `inventory` 
LEFT JOIN mod_inventory_equip_types AS `equipTypes` 
       ON `equipTypes`.equip_type_id = `inventory`.equip_type_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_vendors_main AS `vendors`  
       ON `vendors`.vendor_id = `inventory`.vendor_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_inventory_status AS `status`  
       ON `status`.status_id = `inventory`.status_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_locations_data AS `locations`  
       ON `locations`.location_id = `inventory`.location_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_locations_rooms AS `rooms`  
       ON `rooms`.room_id = `inventory`.room_id 
LEFT JOIN mod_users_data AS `enteredBy`  
       ON `enteredBy`.user_id = `inventory`.entered_by
LEFT JOIN mod_workorder_counts AS at  
       ON at.asset_tag = inventory.asset_tag 
ORDER BY inventory_id ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

It executes in 0.0051 seconds.  That puts a total between the two queries at 0.1631 seconds which is near 1/10th of a second versus 15+ seconds with the original subquery.

If I just included the field "wo_count" without using the COALESCE, I got NULL values for any asset tags that were not listed in the "mod_workorder_counts" table.  So the COALESCE would give me a 0 for any NULL value, which is what I want.

Now I will set it up so that when a work order is entered for an asset tag, i'll have the INSERT/UPDATE query for the counts table update at that time so it doesn't run unnecessarily.